# Can‘t access Windows after deleting Ubuntu partitions

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I wanted to get rid of my dual boot system and deleted the partitions, where Ubuntu was on. So I deleted partition 5,6,7 and extended the OS(C.:). I left partition 1 (EFI System Partion).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7H1m.jpg)

After restarting it shows a black screen „GNU GRUB version 2.04“ after manufacturers logo, and I dont know what to do.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq3SV.jpg)

Can you help? :(

Comment: Before deleting an OS, ensure the OS you are keeping controls the boot process. Usually the last installed controls the boot process, so you made the mistake of removing the Ubuntu OS before you put windows in control of booting. You can correct this using your Windows Recovery media (*note: commands can vary depending on the version of windows you're using*)

Comment: So all data ist completely lost?

Comment: No your data is safe; you just have to recover the windows boot process (*the installation of a second OS will cause the second or last-installed to control the boot process; Ubuntu in your case.  All OSes have command(s) that make them control booting; windows recovery media can fix windows so it'll boot rather than being told to boot by Ubuntu*)

Comment: eg.  the currently 171 UPVOTED answer in the duplicate post walks you through the process, though there are (*as always*) many ways to fix this.

Comment: @guiverc: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recovery-options-in-windows-31ce2444-7de3-818c-d626-e3b5a3024da5    „Use Installation media to reinstall Windows 10“ is the right option ?

Comment: Sorry; I'm not a windows user and thus have not [*recently; in in 3+ years*] performed what you're asking for... thus I'd suggest you use a windows support site

Comment: If you have a Windows specific question that goes on the superuser.com site.

Comment: You likely need to only change your system boot priority to boot Windows bootloader first. If you're not sure how to configure boot priority on your system, check the documentation or support for the model motherboard that your computer has. Configuring boot priority is a feature of your motherboard and is different between manufacturers and sometimes different between different models from the same manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is When you deleted the partitions where Ubuntu was on, you also deleted the GRUB bootloader.

To fix this, you need to reinstall GRUB.

Download the GRUB 2 ISO file from the GRUB website https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-download.html.
Burn the ISO file to a CD or USB drive.
Boot your computer from the CD or USB drive.
Follow the on-screen instructions to install GRUB.

Comment: I have to vote down this answer because it is a wrong answer to the question that was asked. OP wants to remove Ubuntu and keep Windows. Additionally, OP has already deleted the Ubuntu partitions. To reinstall GRUB is incorrect.

Comment: You can boot Windows from GRUB I do it everyday.

Comment: This is clearly not what OP is looking for. And on a single boot system with Windows only, using GRUB is not only pointless, it just adds unnecessary steps to the boot sequence. GRUB does not actually perform any Windows related booting actions, it simply hands off to the Windows bootloader.